How does a structural engineer go about calculating a tie-plate's load-rating when the manufacturer hasn't load rated it?
Manufacturers of gang-nail truss plates, the kind with fasteners punched out of the plate itself, typically load-rate them but they leave truss mending plates or "tie-plates" that accept common nails not load rated, and in their documentation they defer to the Engineer of Record to determine the load a particular plate can handle. When the engineer knows the dimensions of the plate, the gauge of steel, and the diameter and number of holes that accept the common nails or  screws called out by the manufacturer, what resource does the engineer consult to determine maximum load rating  and various intermediary load ratings based on the total number of fasteners used?

well any load rating will be affected drastically by the nails used, cheap soft etc etc

Yes, of course.  But if the fasteners are those called out by the manufacturer, how does the Engineer of Record determine what load a particular plate/fastener configuration can handle? Are there ISO standards to consult, say?  A given fastener in a plate of a given gauge can handle X load, and then there's some multiplier?

Someone might consult a similar plate and throw a big ol factor of safety over it. A plate where you supply fasteners is generally just treated as steel.

The nails shear strength or pull-out strength determines the allowable strength of the gang plate. For example, an 8 d common nail 0.131 in by 1.5 in has a shear value range of 100-150 depending on the case.
Depending on the judgement of the design engineer if the connection is generating torque or off center stresses, it has to be designed for rotation and has to be calculated by equations such as
$$F_i = \frac{T \cdot r_i}{\sum r_i^2} $$

$F_i=load\  of\  each\  nail$
$r_i= distance \ of \ nail \ to \ center\ of \ nail\ pack$
$T= joint\ torque$

Here is the link to 2018 National Design Center for wood in US , It has tables for a variety of nail, bolt, and screw connections.  NDS wood design aid

Excellent. Thanks. A follow-up question if I may.  When I visit sites where builders  (not engineers)  come to discuss the practical use of such plates, a frequent question takes the form "Surely we shouldn't be putting a nail in every hole of the plate, putting nearly sixty 8d nails in a 5-inch by 7-inch area?! That would make the lumber nail-poor and turn it into toothpicks".  Is there a technical engineering term for "nail-poor", or a term for the number of nails of a given size that a piece of dimensional lumber can support per square inch, or something like that?

@Tim please post that in a new question

@jsotola I would have to reiterate the entire plate context of the original question in order for that followup  question to make sense. Knowing stackexchange, someone would close it as a duplicate and ask me to explain how it is different. So I  would prefer to leave it as a directly related question in the comment.

@Tim, no. the the pattern of holes give the designer choice of following best alignment of nails with the angle of joint and management of stresses.  We used to have a library of connection details with known properties. we circled their call out numbers on the plans and attached the entire library to permit set.

@kamran Thank you again.
